# Parsing json in backbone

Tags: json, parsing, backbone.js

```
prodCollect.fetch({
                    success: function(collection){
                    console.log(prodCollect.models.length); 



                    var a =prodCollect.models[1];
                    console.log(a.attributes);
                    var y=_(a.attributes).toArray();
                    console.log(y[0]);



                     }
                });
```

In variable 'a', I'm getting a model and doing console(a.attributes), I'm getting this:

```
Object {[{"product_id":"2","product_name":"new product","short_description":"used for training of managers","full_description":"used for training of managers","price":"20000.00","acct_manager":"rahul raja","roles":"Manager,Manager","tags":"abc,def","skills":"abc,abc","clients":"accenture,accenture,Wipro,Google"}]: Object}
```

Now I am unable to access the properties like 'product_name' and 'price'. I tried converting a.attributes into an array and accessing y[0] but its undefined. 'a.attributes' is an object. So I am unable to access the properties.

I am sending this from server

```
[
   "[{\"program_name\":\"training\",\"products\":\"new product,fdgf\",\"roles\":\"Manager,CEO,random\",\"tags\":\"abc,def\",\"skills\":\"abc,def\",\"clients\":\"accenture,wipro\"},{\"program_name\":\"New progs\",\"products\":\"fdgf,ILead\",\"roles\":\"CEO,Manager,random\",\"tags\":\"abc,def\",\"skills\":\"abc,def\",\"clients\":\"\"}]",
   "[{\"product_id\":\"2\",\"product_name\":\"new product\",\"short_description\":\"used for training of managers\",\"full_description\":\"used for training of managers\",\"price\":\"20000.00\",\"acct_manager\":\"rahul raja\",\"roles\":\"Manager,Manager\",\"tags\":\"abc,def\",\"skills\":\"abc,abc\",\"clients\":\"accenture,accenture,Wipro,Google\"}]"


]
```

so variable 'a' contains the second array

Comment: prodCollect is a collection and a.attributes is consequently an object. So how do i access the array inside the object and then the values? I have spent 2 hours on this thing so please dont tell me to google it.

Comment: `a.attributes[0].product_name`

Comment: a.attributes[0] is giving undefined

Comment: What happens if you get the model like `prodCollect.at(1)`?

Comment: it gives the same result as prodCollect.models[1]

Comment: And then `a.get('product_name');`?

Comment: I have got the answer. The JSON which i am sending actually contains 2 strings rather than 2 arrays(as indicated by the double quotes). Thats why it was giving all the problems in parsing.

Comment: Even i had the same problem. Got it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem came from the server, your log should be like :

```
{
    "product_id": "2",
    "product_name": "new product",
    "short_description": "used for training of managers",
    "full_description": "used for training of managers",
    "price": "20000.00",
    "acct_manager": "rahul raja",
    "roles": "Manager,Manager",
    "tags": "abc,def",
    "skills": "abc,abc",
    "clients": "accenture,accenture,Wipro,Google"
}
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/PqLeb/) that illustrate what I suspected your server doing.

---

So as I suspected, your problem came from the server. Your server response should be like that :

```
[
    {
        "product_id": "2",
        "product_name": "new product",
        ...
    },
    {
        "product_id": "2",
        "product_name": "new product",
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: i have edited the question regarding what i am sending from the server

Comment: ya,its two arrays inside an array

Comment: So you problem came from the server ?